# Как покинуть discord сервер по его идентификатору в discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Мне необходимо сделать команду ">server-leave [id сервера]", по которой discord бот будет покидать этот сервер которого id я укажу при вызове. Целый день пытаюсь решить эту легкую задачку, но все коды которые я использовал из документации / вопросов других пользователей просто не работают. Пожалуйста, помогите. Вот код который я имею, и он не рабочий:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['server-leave'])
async def __leave_from_server(ctx, serverid = None):

if ctx.author.id in devlist:

    if serverid == None:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = "Укажите id сервера"))
    else:
        try:
            toleave = bot.get_guild(serverid)
            await bot.leave_guild(toleave)
            await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = "Успешно"))
        except:
            try:
                toleave = bot.get_guild(serverid)
                await toleave.leave()
                await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = "Успешно"))
            except:
                await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = "Ошибка"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку `Python` - язык с динамической типизацией, по умолчанию все, полученные в качестве аргументов, значения  принимают строковый тип `str`, так как фактически были получены из строки (`str`), содержащей текст сообщения.

Функция `get_guild()` принимает в качестве аргумента `id` сервера в виде целого числа (`int`), а вы подаете строку (`str`).

Чтобы вручную не выполнять приведение типов (`serverid = int(serverid)`), можно просто указать тип аргумента в функции:

```py
async def __leave_from_server(ctx, serverid: int=None):
```

---

**Дополнительно:**

Чтобы не использовать `if-else` и не создавать лишних отступов, можно при несоблюдении условия вызывать возврат функции (`return`), что будет прерывать ее дальнейшее выполнение.

**Без `return`:**

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['server-leave'])
async def __leave_from_server(ctx, serverid: int=None):
    if ctx.author.id in devlist:
        if serverid == None:
            await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = "Укажите id сервера"))
        else:
            # Ошибок нет, функцию можно выполнять
```

**С использованием `return`:**

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['server-leave'])
async def __leave_from_server(ctx, serverid: int=None):
    if ctx.author.id not in devlist:
        return
    if serverid == None:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = "Укажите id сервера"))
        return
    # Ошибок нет, функцию можно выполнять
```